# If s1 and s2 are the spin operators of two electrons, FInd out (s1 .s2) for the singlet and triplet states of hydrogen molecule

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics

If s1 and s2 are the spin operators of two electrons, FInd out (s1 .s2) for
the singlet and triplet states of hydrogen molecule.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: If you search for singlet and triplet within this site, you immediately get a few answers.

Comment: While Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).